# Include custom fonts in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, fonts

Does Anyone know something like *ebextensions*[2] in EC2 for AWS Lambda?

The goal is to *install* custom fonts in the AWS Lambda execution environment.

There are many ways to provide libraries and tools with fonts but the easiest way would be to include them via OS.

Also asked in response on AWS forum: 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=807139&#807139

[2][How I install specific fonts on my AWS EC2 instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28270306/how-i-install-specific-fonts-on-my-aws-ec2-instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official AWS response on the forum post is still correct.

> Currently, it is not possible to customize Lambda environment. If you want additional packages you can build on Amazon Linux and put them into the zip file you upload.

That's the extent to which you can "install" anything in the Lambda environment.

> the easiest way would be to include them via OS.

Arguably so, but that's simply not how Lambda works.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts.
Thats why I hoped that AWS would provide something like a wrapper funcitonality, to add fonts like e.g.  _ebextensions_ in EC2.

Answer (score 39):

Here's what I just got to work for custom fonts on AWS Lambda with pandoc/xelatex.

I created a `fonts` directory in my project and placed all of my fonts there. Also in that directory I created a `fonts.conf` file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <dir>/var/task/fonts/</dir>
  <cachedir>/tmp/fonts-cache/</cachedir>
  <config></config>
</fontconfig>
```

And then in my (node.js based) handler function before shelling out to call pandoc I set an ENV var to tell fontconfig where to find the fonts.

```
process.env.FONTCONFIG_PATH='/var/task/fonts'
```

After doing that I can refer to a font, like `Bitter`, in my template by name (just `Bitter`) and then pandoc/xelatex/fontconfig/whatever knows which version of the font to use (like `Bitter-Bold.otf` vs `Bitter-Italic.otf`) based on the styling that any bit of text is supposed to have.

I figured this out based on the tips in this project for getting RSVG to work with custom fonts on Lambda: https://github.com/claudiajs/rsvg-convert-aws-lambda-binary/blob/master/README.md#using-custom-fonts

Comment: This is the answer that helped me out.

Comment: The same strategy works on a Lambda layer, as well, but instead of `/var/task/` use `/opt`

Comment: This worked for me too - for anyone confused, stuff you deploy to a lambda function gets dumped in /var/task - and in my case, we deploy multiple packages, so /var/task/packageName. There are also some differences between nodejs8.10 and nodejs10.x -- https://github.com/alestic/lambdash helped a lot too - I checkout out, updated for node10 and installed. Pretty handy!

Comment: this worked for me: http://techdebtcollect.blogspot.com/2018/10/how-to-get-custom-font-into-aws-lambda.html, the difference from Jeremy's fonts.conf is that the <dir></dir> points to a relative URL "./fonts" (I haven't tried with fully qualified url, but my guess it will work as well)

Comment: The font config doesn't really work for me. I am using the node gm package to interact with ImageMagick (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm), and whether or not I include the fonts.conf file, it only accepts a relative path to my font (e.g. `fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf`).

Comment: the `fonts.conf` worked for me, but not the env var `FONTCONFIG_PATH`. I had to use a different env var, `FONTCONFIG_FILE`. See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html

Comment: Could you provide gist example on how to do that? I try to make the same with lambda function in aws amplify project

Answer (score 3):

A lot of the answer on this subject of using fonts on Lambda's were a bit incomplete.

My scenario required using a custom font in conjunction with Imagemagick. I checked out out this [branch with Imagemagick and Freetype support](https://github.com/sw360cab/imagemagick-aws-lambda-2.git) and worked through the [README](https://github.com/sw360cab/imagemagick-aws-lambda-2/tree/master). The key for my use case is the lambda or lambda layer used in the function needed freetype support to access my fonts. I'm using a TTF.

After deploying the lambda layer, in my Lambda function's directory I did the following:

- At the root of my lambda create a `fonts` directory.

  - In the `fonts` directory add the TTF or your font.

    - I'm using serverless framework so this directory once deployed will be located at `/var/task/fonts`.
  - Also in the `fonts` directory include the following `fonts.conf`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <dir>/var/task/fonts/</dir>
  <cachedir>/tmp/fonts-cache/</cachedir>
  <config></config>
</fontconfig>
```

- Finally, in your serverless.yml add the following directory so that your fonts and fonts.conf will be included in the lambda.

```
package:
    include:
        - fonts/**
```

Because freetype is now accessible in the lambda layer any fonts in the fonts directory will be accessible. Could have also dynamically downloaded fonts needed, but I decided to choose include in my lambda function.

Comment: What does including the `fonts/fonts.conf` file do? It didn't seem to make any difference for me. Whether I have the file or not, I have to use a path to the TTF itself, rather than refer to the font by name.

Answer (score 1):

Package your assets along with the code or have it fetch them from s3. This is the way we generate PDFs with custom fonts with Lambda.

Things like the [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws) will do this for you automatically (uploading code + deps assets).

When you `deploy` it will create a zip file with your code, dependencies and anything else you have in the folder. Then it will automatically upload it to S3 and deploy it with the help of CloudFormation.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. 
That is exactly how I'm doing it right now. 
But AFAIK fonts are still just assets files which have no realation to the operating system therefore in used libraries they need to be included again. 

Since this is not possible for me due to unexpected behaviour:(https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/4355), I hoped for something like ebextensions for lamba functions.

Comment: Cannot seems to bundle them correctly, can you post an example ? I think I tried everything. :(

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nat-n/c3429d29f2478ccb3de243810bb12956) and it worked a charm (although for me in the "Configuring fontconfig" and "Installing and caching fonts" sections the `/tmp/…/fontconfig` seemed to really mean `/var/task/<MyLambda>/headless-chrome/fontconfig`)

Answer (score 0):

Lambda extracts the layer contents into the [/opt directory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) when setting up the execution environment for the function.  So, fonts.conf should have /opt/.fonts under  and ttf fonts should be placed there.

In addition Lambda needs to access the fontconfig library like libfontconfig.so, libexpat.so and libfreetype.so. The files can be found in [phantom-lambda-fontconfig-pack](https://github.com/naeemshaikh27/phantom-lambda-fontconfig-pack).

It seems that it works in Node.JS lambda. In case of using Python Lambda, it still does not work.

At last, I created a Lambda container image based on the dockerfile in [rchauhan9/image-scraper-lambda-container](https://github.com/rchauhan9/image-scraper-lambda-container) and then added the following code after "RUN apk add chromium..."

```
ENV NOTO_TC="https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-cjk/raw/main/Sans/Variable/OTF/NotoSansCJKhk-VF.otf"
ENV NOTO_SC="https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-cjk/raw/main/Sans/Variable/OTF/NotoSansCJKsc-VF.otf"
ENV NOTO_JP="https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-cjk/raw/main/Sans/Variable/OTF/NotoSansCJKjp-VF.otf"
ENV NOTO_KR="https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-cjk/raw/main/Sans/Variable/OTF/NotoSansCJKkr-VF.otf"
RUN apk --no-cache add \
      fontconfig \
      wget \
      && mkdir -p /usr/share/fonts \
      && wget -q "${NOTO_TC}" -P /usr/share/fonts \
      && wget -q "${NOTO_SC}" -P /usr/share/fonts \
      && wget -q "${NOTO_JP}" -P /usr/share/fonts \
      && wget -q "${NOTO_KR}" -P /usr/share/fonts \
      && fc-cache -fv

ENV LANG="C.UTF-8"
```

It works with CJK fonts. Reference: Section "Building a Custom Image for Python" in [New for AWS Lambda – Container Image Support](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/)