# Python - How to install font on AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, fonts, aws-lambda, installation

I'm trying to install a font on AWS Lambda to use TextClip() function of moviepy. 
I followed step by step this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51622335/6673340, but the font still doesn't want to instal...

I have the following files and dir in my deployement package :

[image]

This is my fonts.conf :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <dir>/opt/fonts/</dir>
  <cachedir>/tmp/fonts-cache/</cachedir>
  <config></config>
</fontconfig>
```

And I also add : `FONTCONFIG_PATH=/opt/fonts`

But I still get the following error :

```
[ERROR] OSError: MoviePy Error: creation of None failed because of the following error:

convert: unable to read font `Rubik-Regular' @ warning/annotate.c/RenderType/955.
convert: delegate library support not built-in 'Rubik-Regular' (Freetype) @ warning/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1808.
convert: no images defined `PNG32:/tmp/tmp3h8xrg3n.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3300
```

Do either of you know why this isn't working for me?

Comment: hey I am facing the same issue. Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
/var/task is the directory where you codebase lives as per lambda convention 

so as per your current structure i think FONTCONFIG_PATH=/var/task/fonts

and font.conf should be 

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <dir>/var/task/fonts/</dir>
  <cachedir>/tmp/fonts-cache/</cachedir>
  <config></config>
</fontconfig>
```

Comment: Do not just add code to a answer, explaint the code and specifically address the questioner's problems.