# Errors running headless chromium in AWS Lambda

Tags: java, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver

I have been stuck trying to get this to work for literal weeks, so any help would be much appreciated.

I'm trying to run selenium tests written in Java in AWS Lambda. I turned on verbose logging in webdriver and here is the output (stack traces omitted):

```
[1615217980.576][INFO]: Launching chrome: /tmp/chrome_headless12660738644101056992/headless-

chromium --data-path=/tmp --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-profile --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-extensions --disable-gpu --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-security --disk-cache-dir=/tmp --enable-automation --enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0 --enable-logging --headless --homedir=/tmp --ignore-certificate-errors --log-level=0 --no-first-run --no-sandbox --no-service-autorun --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=0 --single-process --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir=/tmp --window-size=1366,768
[0308/153940.757451:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(431)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale 
prctl(PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS) failed
prctl(PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS) failed
[0308/153942.834268:WARNING:discardable_shared_memory_manager.cc(194)] Less than 64MB of free space in temporary directory for shared memory files: 0
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:41157/devtools/browser/563821ec-8b24-4a54-b834-d4d2ed23d8a2
[0308/153942.914879:ERROR:devtools_http_handler.cc(291)] Error writing DevTools active port to file
[0308/153942.932365:ERROR:egl_util.cc(70)] Failed to load GLES library: /tmp/chrome_headless12660738644101056992/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so: /tmp/chrome_headless12660738644101056992/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[0308/153942.933136:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(81)] Failed to create directory: /tmp/Default/Code Cache/js
[0308/153942.933684:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(81)] Failed to create directory: /tmp/Default/Code Cache/js
[0308/153942.933708:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(757)] Simple Cache Backend: wrong file structure on disk: 1 path: /tmp/Default/Code Cache/js
[0308/153942.934435:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(81)] Failed to create directory: /tmp/Default/Code Cache/wasm
[0308/153942.934494:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(81)] Failed to create directory: /tmp/Default/Code Cache/wasm
[0308/153942.934503:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(757)] Simple Cache Backend: wrong file structure on disk: 1 path: /tmp/Default/Code Cache/wasm
[0308/153942.955102:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(184)] Unable to create cache
[0308/153942.955146:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(606)] Shader Cache Creation failed: -2
[0308/153942.972843:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(749)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: Failed to create shared context for virtualization.
[0308/153942.972880:ERROR:shared_image_stub.cc(471)] SharedImageStub: unable to create context
[0308/153942.972890:ERROR:gpu_channel.cc(449)] GpuChannel: Failed to create SharedImageStub
[0308/153942.952932:FATAL:platform_font_skia.cc(97)] Check failed: InitDefaultFont(). Could not find the default font
Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.
[1615217983.174][INFO]: [11c2ef49b3c2bcd0ed0121c5a7d97ab7] RESPONSE InitSession ERROR unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
(unknown error: Devtools port number file contents <> were in an unexpected format)
(The process started from chrome location /tmp/chrome_headless12660738644101056992/headless-chromium is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
[1615217983.175][DEBUG]: Log type 'driver' lost 0 entries on destruction
[1615217983.175][DEBUG]: Log type 'browser' lost 0 entries on destruction
Failures: 2
Success: -1
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
```

So there's a lot of errors about not being able to create directories (I've searched for these ones as well, but couldn't find out why it's not able to write)... but anyway the "fatal" one is complaining about the default font. I've read that Amazon Linux has no fonts installed so to get chrome to work on it, you need to install one. So I followed the procedure here: [Include custom fonts in AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46486261/include-custom-fonts-in-aws-lambda). But here we still see the error:

```
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
```

So this makes it sound like the path is null. But I'm setting both in the env vars:
[image]

And here is the folder structure:

[image]

And fonts.conf:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
   <dir>/var/task/lambda_fonts/</dir>
   <cachedir>/tmp/fonts-cache/</cachedir>
   <config></config>
</fontconfig>
```

So why is Lambda not finding the path?

Also here are the config options I'm passing to chromedriver, in case there's anything that jumps out at you:

```
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");           
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1366,768");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--single-process");
        
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--user-data-dir=/tmp");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--data-path=/tmp");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--homedir=/tmp");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disk-cache-dir=/tmp");
        
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-profile");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
```

Comment: I don't know much about this but when it comes to file path stuff, my guess is the chromeOptions class isn't finding the files in tmp... What happens if you copy the font file to the /tmp directory? Will it work? If it does then you know the file path chromeOptions is using is incorrect and might need to be set with the addArguments function?

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz, I tried your suggestion, and it made me realize that actually my fonts directory wasn't being included in the jar. So fixing that got rid of the `Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file` error, but `InitDefaultFont(). Could not find the default font` still persists. Copying the fonts file into /tmp didn't make any difference though. So I think it's finding the font config, but maybe I have to also set the default font somehow?

Comment: what about running these commands? `export FONTCONFIG_FILE=/var/task/lamba_fonts/fonts.conf` and `export FONTCONFIG_PATH=/var/task/lamba_fonts`

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz do you mean in my Java program? I tried logging the env vars using `System.getenv()` and they are indeed being set.

Comment: trying running those commands in the shell before running the java program. But if doing `echo $FONTCONFIG_FILE` in the shell outputs your desired path then it should be finding the font files. Is there a default directory for which the chromedriver will look for the files? Try putting those files in that default folder?

Comment: By in the shell do you mean when you're running the lambda inside a docker image? I haven't gotten that work yet unfortunately. I think it's the headless chromium that is failing because of the font, not chromedriver. But I'm not aware of any default directory. The issue is that Amazon Linux 2 in Lambda doesn't have any fonts installed, so to use chrome, you have to install them yourself. So I think it's it's just the OS failing to find any default font installed.

Comment: Have you thought about not running Chrome in your Lambda function and perhaps using AWS Device Farm browser testing (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/testgrid/what-is-testgrid.html)? Not only is it going to be far more scalable, but you'll also have more browsers to play with, and you can download/stream video playback of your sessions. And, it's pretty reasonably priced

Comment: No I haven't considered that @user3067870. What I ended up doing was creating an EC2 instance to run a Jenkins server which runs the test, since Lambda was giving me so many problems. It might be a little overkill, device farm could be the way to go.